# Which expression after "than" is correct in this case?

Tags: grammar

Which expression after "than" is correct in this case?

1. You may have visited more places in China than me.
2. You may have visited more places in China than I did.
3. Or neither above is correct. Then what's the correct sentence?

Comment: If comparing our travels, go with #2.  #1 means you visited China sites more than you visited me, and I envy China.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Taller than me" or "taller than I"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103699/taller-than-me-or-taller-than-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In casual conversation, most people will say "You did this more than me..."

The grammatically correct form is this: "You have visited more places in China than I have."

The word "have" can be left off the end.

Comment: It is accepted by many grammarians that 'You have done more than me' is the preferred and hence grammatical form nowadays. This has already been discussed in a duplicate, [I can run faster than him/he](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/i-can-run-faster-than-1-him-2-he). Supporting evidence, as ELU virtually requires, is given there.

Comment: Also, both options you listed at the top in your question are correct. Well, let me edit this. If we are being nit picky it's really only option 1 and we would change option 2 to end with "I have".